# Chrome extension - select from drop down menu if value contains certain string

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

How can I select value from drop down menu if it contains certain string ?
Drop down menus contains time values like 10:20, 10:25, 10:30, 10:35, 10:40, 10:45.

I want the option to be selected which has time value XX:15 or XX:45 (where XX can be what ever hour).

something like this:

```
$('.option_row_panel', $content).each(function(i) {
 var minutes = [15,45];
 $('.option_row_expiry_list option:contains("' + 15 + '")').attr('selected', true);
 $('.option_row_expiry_list option:contains("' + 45 + '")').attr('selected', true);
});
```

This way I can select wanted option but how can I do it with single line ?

Thank you

Comment: So your `select` is a `multiple` ... and you want to select all entries that contain the minutes mentioned in the `minutes` array? I don't think you can do that with a single line ... why would you want to? Only for performance reasons?

Comment: btw, you should use `.prop()` rather than `.attr()` to set the property instead of the attribute. The property can have the values `true` or `false` whereas the attribute doesn't have a value

Comment: Well actually.. There is only XX:15 or XX:45 but never both of them. So that being said I always select only one.
Is this right ?
$('.option_row_expiry_list option:contains("' + 15 + '")').prop('selected', true);

Comment: I would add the colon to the selector to avoid `15:30` from being selected for minute `15`: `$('.option_row_expiry_list option:contains(":15")').prop('selected', true);`

Comment: couldn't get that to work at all..

Comment: Can you show the HTML markup of the select including its options?

Comment: <select class="option_mode_info_expiry_list">
 <option value="6597580">13:25</option>
 <option value="6596557">13:30</option>
 <option value="6597649">13:35</option>
 <option value="6597737">13:40</option>
 <option value="6597681">13:45</option>
 <option value="6597533">14:00</option>
 <option value="6597191">14:30</option>
 <option value="6595614">23:00</option>
 <option value="6585901">6/06 23:00</option>
<option value="6614832">30/06 22:00</option></select>

Comment: $('.option_row_expiry_list option:contains("15")').prop('selected', true); 
this works nicely, but if there is ":15" then no..

Comment: There is another problem too.. Even though it looks like right option value is selected if I continue on the page (click submit) right after that wrong value will be selected.. Looks like the right value is not really selected and page just takes the first value from the drop down menu. Should I use clickOn to avoid this and how ?

Comment: clickOn resolves the problem.

Comment: The right way to select a value in a non-multiple select would be to set the value property of the select rather than the selected attribute of the option: `$('.option_mode_info_expiry_list').val("13:15")`

Comment: I mean clickOn cause Im simulating clicks to the site via chrome extension.

Comment: I have no idea what clickOn is

Comment: Is there change to use regexp, cause I need to use XX:15 or XX:45. Now my system goes crazy if time is 15:XX .
regexp could be something like **:15 or **:45 .
$('.option_row_expiry_list option:contains("regexp_here")').prop('selected', true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way to trigger the required events so that supposedly all of the attached event handlers will be called

```
function simulateEvent(eventname, element) {
  var event = new MouseEvent(eventname, {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

So you might be able to simulate the click on the option as well as the change of the select (inside the `.each()` of the previous answer)

```
simulateEvent('click', $(this)[0]);
simulateEvent('change', $(this).closest('select')[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you devnull69, that does it. This truly helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

Example using Regex

```
$('.option_row_expiry_list option').each(function() {
   if($(this).text().match(/\:15/)) {
      $(this).closest('select').val($(this).val());
   }
});
```

Comment: Now this is weird.. With devnull69's example I get right value to be selected but again after clicking submit the page selects one option before selected option not the one selected. To make this even more weirder, if I choose manually something else than devnull69's code is selecting those are working nicely after submit.

Comment: Are there any `onchange` (or similar) handlers in place?

Comment: Nope.. If I use your code to select option and then I choose some else option and after that I choose again the option your code selected then its working. Weird.

Comment: Feels like the selected option isn't "really" selected (just looks like it is).. I need to select it manually to get it really selected and right after that is is working.

Comment: if ($(this).not(':selected')) { console.log('nothing selected'); }
Im not sure if this is right, but this is saying "nothing selected" right after your code devnull69.

Comment: Did you (by any chance) use a handler on the submit button to change the select value *and* submit the form? Does your select have a `name` attribute?

Comment: Nope.. Submit only submits the form.

Comment: Please check this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/siliz/2/edit ... it shows the property `selected` to be true as well as `.is(':selected')`. Also the submit button serializes the form correctly with the (automatically) selected value, so I cannot reproduce the issue on Chrome 35

Comment: Yep I can see it's working perfectly. I think this has something to do with the chrome extension. Im not sure do I need to use clickOn to actually simulate clicks to those options. I tried to use clickOn to your code but that attempt failed..
clickOn($(this).closest('select').val($(this).val()));
clickOn($(this).closest('select').val($(this).val());

None of those worked.

Comment: Did I mention that `clickOn` does not ring any bell? Is it one of your own methods?

Comment: To be honest.. Im not even sure how does that work.. I have one content script which is coded by someone else and it uses codes like
clickOn($("span.ig-form-payout")[0]);  and clickOn($("div.message_popup").find("div.message_popup_close")[0]);   and those works perfectly. I googled clickOn and I found nothing. Weird.

Comment: devnull69: how can I use .click() on your code ? Like this one $('#element')[0].click() . I need to try that one out too.

Comment: You mean in order to click on the selected option? Check this out: http://jsbin.com/siliz/3/edit

Comment: That looks perfect for me but still no go. I just cannot understand what is the problem here. Again I need to select the option manually to make it work otherwise it just selects the first option after submit.

Comment: Just a little bit of progress.. I noticed that if I click the drop down menu manually lot of things gets updated on the site but when I use devnull69's code then non of those things get updated. Maybe mouse up is the trigger or something like that.

Comment: Im quite sure there needs to trigger somekind of event.. I have tried these, but no luck.. Anyone have any idea ?
$(this).click();
$(this).change();
$(this).mousedown();
$(this).mouseup();
$(this).trigger('change');

Comment: Ok.. There is events bound to that dropdown menu and those events aren't triggered when jquery selects right option. This is the problem.

Comment: Can you find out which code (method) is called inside the respective event handler? You could call that same code/method upon selection of the desired dropdown entry

Comment: Im not 100% sure but looks like this is called on change:
function (){try{return om(b,this,arguments)}catch(a){throw a}}

Comment: this might get difficult ... `this` would be the `select`, but what is `b` and what does `om()` do?

Comment: you should work on reputation and collect at least 13 more so that we could start a chat about it ... extended discussions in comments are strongly deprecated on SO

Comment: om() = function om(a,b,c){var d;d=mm();try{return lm(a,b,c)}finally{pm(d)}}
As you can see this is just a endless task to find out what is happening on those functions. So Im not gonna even try. Easiest thing should be just to trigger the change somehow. While I was crowling google I found this.. https://code.google.com/p/expandselect/ . Im sure something similar to this is made to trigger the change on select.